# How do I represent the infinite number ~0.99999..... in Objective-C / iOS?

Tags: objective-c

I have a number that could potentially go on forever, like ~0.999999...

See this:

```
while (myNumber / 25 > 0.999999)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

How can I represent that number in Objective-C properly?

Or maybe I am doing this `while` loop incorrectly and someone can tell me how to fix it? I'm trying to see if `myNumber` can be divided by 25 at least once... so even 26/25 would pass (mod `%` wouldn't work in this case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fortunately for you, this repeating decimal has an exact representation in floating point arithmetic (you don't have to round):

```
while (myNumber / 25 > 1)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This is because "0.999999..." and "1" are just different ways of writing the same number.  They are **not** different numbers.

Or perhaps you want to do this:

```
while (myNumber / 25 >= 1)
```

If `myNumber` is a non-negative integer, then this is actually the same as:

```
while (myNumber / 25) // nonzero values are "true"
```

Or, you can translate it to the equivalent:

```
while (myNumber >= 25) // no need to divide
```

Comment: while (myNumber >= 25) is correct. I just wasn't thinking today. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If myNumber is greater than or equal to 25, then it can be divided by 25 at least once.